# Android:Hotspot is not detecting all the WiFi devices connected to it (/proc/net/arp)

Tags: java, android, wifi

I am using the following code to scan the wifi devices connected to my Hotspot enabled device. It is detecting almost all the devices except one device. 
following is the code snippet

> public ArrayList getClientList(boolean onlyReachables, int reachableTimeout) {

```
    BufferedReader br = null;
    ArrayList<ClientScanResultSO> result = null;

   try {
        result = new ArrayList<ClientScanResultSO>();
        br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("/proc/net/arp"));
        String line;
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            String[] splitted = line.split(" +");

            if ((splitted != null) && (splitted.length >= 4)) {
                // Basic sanity check
                String mac = splitted[3];
                System.out.println("mac is***************"+ mac);
                if (mac.matches("..:..:..:..:..:..")) {
                    boolean isReachable = InetAddress.getByName(splitted[0]).isReachable(reachableTimeout);
                    String name = InetAddress.getByName(splitted[0]).getHostName();
                    if (!onlyReachables || isReachable) {
                        result.add(new ClientScanResultSO(splitted[0], splitted[3], splitted[5], isReachable, name));
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e(this.getClass().toString(), e.getMessage());
    } finally {
        try {
            br.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(this.getClass().toString(), e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    return result;
}
```

I am unable to find the issue with it. Is "/proc/net/arp" not registering all the device details ? 
can somebody help me in this...thanks!

Comment: Is there anything special about the 1 extra device? Also, I would consider outputting *something* when `splitted.length() < 4`, just in case you're overlooking something there.

Comment: In fact, as a first test, I'd have the `BufferedReader` dump the whole file to LogCat, to get an idea of whether something is weird with the file or with your code.

Comment: @Hbcdev :I dont know why that device is behaving like that...and also if nothing registred in "/proc/net/arp" then it won't come into that if condition.....

Comment: I still think you should try dumping the whole of `BufferedReader` just to be sure about whether the problem is your code, or Android not registering the device in "/proc/net/arp". It also seems weird to me that there's not a cleaner, programmatic way to get at this information, without parsing a system file.

Comment: @Hbcdev:ok..I will definitely try that and I forgt to mention one more thing, that the device is getting detected sometimes & if somtimes not detected , I am hard coding the ip address of the wifi enabled device(as it is showing in the connected device list)  which i am getting from my Hotspot device(Samsung Tab) and afterwards it is getting detected.